# first node from xml

Tags: c#, xml

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

And I need read the author name so this is what I do:

```
XmlNodeList bookList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("book");

foreach (XmlNode node in bookList)
{
    XmlElement bookElement = (XmlElement)node;

    string title = bookElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText;
    string author = bookElement.GetElementsByTagName("author")[0].InnerText;

    string isbn = "";
    if (bookElement.HasAttributes)
    {
        isbn = ""; 
        ;    //bookElement.Attributes["ISBN"].InnerText
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is written by {2}\n", title, isbn, author);
}
```

I do not like to use a `for` loop even though I surely know that it would run only once. Is there a much cleaner method of doing this?

Comment: you can use the first index of booklist like `XmlElement bookElement = (XmlElement)bookList [0];` and then you can remove forloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "modern" way to do this without `for` loops is to write code using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

This code will work if you are sure there is at least 1 book in the XML file. It creates an anonymous type with 3 properties, `Id`, `Author`, and `Title`.

```
using System.Linq; // requires assembly reference to System.Core.dll
using System.Xml.Linq; // requires assembly reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll

// ...

XDocument document = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");
var book =
    (from b in document.Descendants("book")
    select new
    {
        Id = b.Attribute("id").Value,
        Author = b.Element("author").Value,
        Title = b.Element("title").Value
    }).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use XPATH.

For example the path would be

```
/catalog/book[1]/author
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to directly look up "book.title" ... or all book titles ...

you might consider using XPath (open standard) and/or LINQ (Microsoft only):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882630%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may try Linq XML (Import System.Xml.Linq).

For instance,

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 var nodeList = from ele in doc.Descendants("book")
                select new
                  {
                   ID=(string)ele.Attribute("id"),
                   Author=(string)ele.Element("author")
                   }; // Or use FirstOrDefault(); to obtain first node
 foreach (var t in nodeList)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(t.ID + " " + t.Author );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tagged with C#, assuming you have at least .NET 3.5, then linq-to-xml is likely easiest (at least IMHO)

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                        <catalog>
                           <book id=""bk101"">
                              <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
                              <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
                              <genre>Computer</genre>
                              <price>44.95</price>
                              <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
                              <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
                              with XML.</description>
                           </book>
                        </catalog>";
        XElement e = XElement.Parse(xml);

        var books = e.Elements("book");

        foreach (var book in books)
        {
            var title = book.Element("title").Value;
            var author = book.Element("author").Value;
            var isbn = book.Attribute("id").Value;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is written by {2}", title, isbn, author);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and as bobby mentioned, if you know there's at least one book, you can just do var book = books.First();